# How do I see which ARM CPU version I have?

Tags: raspbian, cross-compilation, arm, gcc

When compiling a package for the Pi I came across a message like this:

```
CFLAGS += -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp #-mcpu=cortex-a8
and 
CFLAGS += -mtune=arm1176jzf-s -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard
```

I know the difference between `-march` and `-mtunu`, but what is the difference between `armv7-a` and `arm1176jzf-s`? if I'm looking at a new Pi how do I know what flags and argument I should use?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

At a command prompt, type

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

to view CPU information.

The ARM11 chips use version 6 of the ARM instruction set, ARMv6.  More recent chips from the ARM Cortex range like the Cortex A7, A8 etc all use the ARMv7 instruction set.

All Pi boards are shipped with an ARM11.  The options on the second line look like a better fit for building software for the Pi. The first set of options appears to be for a newer generation of ARM chip.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76668304/confusion-regarding-arm-architecture-used-in-raspberry-pi-4-model-b/77732274#77732274

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the [uname](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname) command? Specifically `uname -a`

Comment: This is giving me the compatible version, not the hardware version (higher)

Comment: Yeah, this command only says `aarch64`... not that useful.

Comment: Very usefull, because it tells me the version! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

as STEJ's answer suggested, run `uname -m`.

If you have `arm64` then it's 64bit and if you have `armv7l`, then it's 32bit

For more information: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=251721

Comment: `armv7l` is an `armv7` instruction set 32 bit, `arm64` is armv7 64 bit?